# Concatenating Multiple String and Texts Together Into A String - Blogger Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

I have 2 questions here :

### **Question 1.**

How to concatenate multiple text and strings into one String variable and return the string?

```
    function TagGen()
    {
    var getTitle="Nidome no Jinsei wo Isekai de Chapter 1 Raw Manga";
    var getTag=getTitle.substring(0, getTitle.lastIndexOf(" Chapter"));
    var setTags={""+getTitle+", "+getTitle+" Raw Manga"+", "+getTitle+", "+getTag+" Raw Manga"+", "+getTag+" Raw"+", "+getTag+" Manga Download"+", "+getTag+" Download"+", "+getTag+" jcafe"+", "+getTag+" Chapter Download,"+", "+getTag+" Raw Chapters"+", "+getTag+" jcafe24"+", "+"Raw Download"+", "+getTitle+" Raw Manga Download"+", "+getTitle+" jcafe"};
    return setTags;
    }
```

I want the setTags to be have the string value something like the below,

I tried to run this code several times in Tryit Editor but didn't get **setTags** variable working. Please help.

### **Question 2.**

I want to store multiple tags of my blogger blog post into one String.
I know that there must be some b:loop used but I still have not yet fully understood its uses.

**Suppose I have a post with the labels : Action,Adventure,Romance,Shounen**

I want it to get all those labels and store it in a String like:

> **labels**=Action,Adventure,Romance,Shounen

The basic idea of the saving into String is same as the first question but I don't know how to get multiple tags and do it.

**Please help** :D

Comment: Does `var setTags` meant to be an array ? Because `var setTags={""+getTitle+", "+...}` is not a valid syntax.

Comment: It's okay if it's any array also, but how to return it as one single text?

Comment: if you intent to use `{ ... }` know what these are used for. Remove them because you aren't even creating an object. (invalid syntax). To concatenate a string, you only need a `+`. If you insist to use an array, please lookup how to work with arrays in javascript.

Comment: @yashas123 Just remove `{...}` and you'll have a concatenated string.

Comment: LOL, 1st question answer was so near and yet I didn't notice, THANKS!

Comment: What about the second question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the labels present in a post into a variable in a concatenated form, you can use the following code -

```
<script>
    var labelArray = <b:eval expr='data:post.labels map (label => label.name)' />;
    var labels = labelArray.join(',');
</script>
```

This utilizes the [Lambda operator](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/blogger/l3phi8bscGY) `map` provided by Blogger.

Comment: Ok, and suppose I want to get one label at a time? will it be stored in something like labelArray[0] and labelArray[1] and so on manner?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, you can access the individual labels via the notation labelArray[i]